# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on computer

Tags: apache, connection, connection-refused

I am currently encountering a very strange error. I am using Google Chrome and Firefox for testing on my local computer. On my root server there's Debian installed and as panel vesta control panel.

I've associated my domain with the panel and everything's being fine except one thing: I randomly can't get to my webserver by entering my domain with https://www.domain.tld/. Sometimes (very rarely) it's working, but it's most likely to be not working.

On my other Windows root server I can access the site easily with the domain (using a Cloudflare SSL certificate), but my home network  (at least my computer) isn't able to.

I don't know what to do...

Maybe check if this page is working for you:

https://www.mrxidevelopment.de/img/img1439586803_2015.png

(This is a picture of this topic)

Regards

Comment: if you go to that url with another browser do you still have the issue ?

Comment: Yep, tested it using Chrome and Firefox

Comment: you could try with curl or openssl s_client to see if it really comes from the ssl

Comment: I've restarted the entire server and now it's working.

Comment: And now it's not working again..

Comment: https://www.mrxidevelopment.de/img/img1439588662_2015.png please check if you get to this link

Comment: what do you have when you execute curl -v -k https://www.mrxidevelopment.de  ?

Comment: I don't know how to publish that here?

Comment: You are talking about curl output ? you can take a picture. Do you have access to curl command  on your machine ?

Comment: https://www.mrxidevelopment.de/img/img1439590960_2015.png That's it

Comment: Im sorry could you add https : curl -v -k https://www.mrxidevelopment.de (https is not showing in comment)

Comment: I don't get what youre saying?

Comment: could you add curl -v -k https ://mrxidevelopment.de (without space doesnt display in comment otherwise)

Comment: some routers dont let you view the outside domain from inside the network as a security precaution